# как в CSS сделать неподвижным экран на мобайле?

Tags: css

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]Сделал сайт, в мобильном варианте при проверке на десктопе все работает нормально, но при проверке на мобильном телефоне экран не зафиксирован и выходит за границы экрана, но когда пальцы сводишь на экране,т.е. уменьшая размер, то сайт становится по размерам экрана.
какое CSS-свойство приписать, чтоб сайт ложился по размеру экрана мобильного телефона и не выходит за пределы чтоб не точить пальцами для уменьшения?

файл ксс:

```
#logo2 {
    height: 50px;
    min-height: 50px;
    width: 50px;
    min-width: 50px;
    margin-left: -25px;
}
.rightxs {
    margin-left: 2px;
}
.rightxs a {
    color: #777;
    font-family: Arial;
}
#name {
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: -15px;
}
body {
    width: 100%;
    display: table;
    overflow-x:hidden;
}
.center {
    text-align: center;
}
.centermenu {
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 16px;
}
.appbadge {
    width: 120px;
    margin-top: 30px;
}
.centerblock {
    color: whitesmoke;
    text-shadow:
        -1px -1px 0 #000,
         1px -1px 0 #000,
        -1px 1px 0 #000,
         1px 1px 0 #000;
}
.whitesmoke {
    color: whitesmoke;
}
a {
    cursor: pointer
}
.menulang {
    list-style-type: none; 
display: inline;
}
p {
    font-size: 19px;
    font-family: Arial,sans-serif;
}
.activeEv{
    border-bottom: 1px solid #0a88d3;
    color: #0a88d3;
}
.imageblock {
    background-image: url("../../images/5.jpg");
    background-position: center;
    width: auto;                 
    height: 420px;
 }
.circle {
    list-style-type: circle;
}
```

Код:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
<title>LingoCard</title>
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Raleway:100,600" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<link href="bootstrap-3/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="bootstrap-3/css/header_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="bootstrap-3/css/footer_style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<link href="bootstrap-3/css/font-awesome.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

text

Comment: что значит нормально? что значит не зафиксирован? что сделать нужно? покажите код, желаемый результат, скрин ошибки, добавьте описание как должно быть, как не должно быть

Comment: вот код body  я прописал в файле style.css, а остальные свойства к конкретным элементам не имеющим значение, не писал, чтоб не загромождать информацией.скрин скинул, описал

Comment: meta tag viewport установлен?

Comment: оооо, не сталкивался с такой штукой, ща посмотрю что это такое, спасибо

Comment: установлен, но это не решило проблему......

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

PS: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: установлен, но это не решило проблему......

Comment: Тогда нужен [mcve].